# Copy modified content to new file in linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

how can we write a shell script in linux to copy a newly added content from a file and append it to another file.

I have a log file where errors will be stored and i am supposed to retrieve the new errors and store it in a database table. I will run a cron job invoking the shell script in a certain interval.

Edited:

Sample Log

```
140530 13:48:57 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: [root@%][test.event] Table 'test.test_event' doesn't exist
140530 13:48:57 [Note] Event Scheduler: [root@%].[test.event] event execution failed.
140530 13:49:57 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: [root@%][test.event] Table 'test.test_event' doesn't exist
140530 13:49:57 [Note] Event Scheduler: [root@%].[test.event] event execution failed.
```

initially i copied this into a file using **cat** but later some more error will be logged, only newly added lines should be logged.how can i do it in a routine basis.

Kindly help! Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simplest case

You can use `tail -f` to keep retrieving data from a file whenever it is appended to, then use `>>` (appending redirect) to append it to your second file.

```
tail -f file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

will "watch" `file1.txt` and append new content to `file2.txt`.

To test that it works, open another terminal and do:

```
echo "Hello!" >> file1.txt
```

You should see "Hello!" appear in `file2.txt`.

**Please note** that this will only work if the underlying I/O operation on `file1.txt` was an actual append. It **won't** work if you open `file1.txt` in a text editor and change its content, for instance. It also won't work as a cron job, because it needs to run continuously.

## With cron

To periodically check for appends, you could do a [diff](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) on an earlier version of the file you saved somewhere, then use `sed` to get only those lines that were appended in the meantime:

```
diff file1_old.txt file1_current.txt | \
sed -r -e '/^[^>]/ d' -e 's/^> //' >> file2.txt
```

But then you have to take care of storing the earlier versions somewhere etc. in your cron job as well.

Comment: I didn't see you wrote you wanted to do it with cron earlier. Added a possible approach on how to do it with cron to my answer.

Comment: pmos, the diff wlth sed results no output. It shows no difference

Comment: Almost i am done with that using  sed -n '/^</p'. But in my file i have < symbol. How will i delete it ?

Comment: Thank u pmos for yur timely help. Working :)

Comment: You're welcome! Why didn't it work for you with > instead of <? Did you switch up the order of files (i.e. diff file1_current.txt file1_old.txt)? The code I posted works fine on my system at least...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to append (catenate) one file with another, use the "cat" command:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > fileall.txt
```

But if you need to modify the contents of a file, I recommend you to use "sed", or "grep" if what you need is a filter.

Sorry, your specification is a bit loose, so I cannot give you a more exact answer.

BTW. Database table? Can you please explain?

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I can append. But how will i identify the newly added content? So that I could able to copy the newly added lines to another file.

Comment: You can add a prefix to the lines, for instance. "sed s/^/prefix-/" will do

Comment: What about clearing the file or rotating it every time its dumped into the database?

Comment: i did that initially. Once after dumping into db and truncating the file, further error logs are not being logged into that file.